# How can I eliminate the added height when applying a thickness to Solidify modifier?

Tags: modifiers

When I add a Solidify modifier to a hemispherical shell, I am given an option to add a thickness (amongst other options). When I add a thickness to the hemispherical shell, I've noticed that Blender increases the overall height of the shell due to the added wall thickness.  An example is shown in the attached image.[image: Shape height increase due to shell thickness]

Is there a way I can eliminate the extra added thickness? Are there additional steps I can take to suppress it, or make the bottom of the hemispherical shell flat again?

Comment: make the thickness a negative value.

Comment: Please list all modifiers if you have more than one.  Do you have a subdivide surface modifier?

Comment: This doesn't work -- this still creates a non-flat profile for the base of the shell. I believe flipping the sign of the Thickness value is the same as flipping the sign of the "Offset" value.

Comment: Atomic -- the only modifiers I'm adding to the shell are: 
- Subdivision Surface (to make it smooth for illustration purposes)
- Thickness modifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Adjust normals

**[Solidify](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/solidify.html)** modifier extrudes faces along their **normal**.

A default UV hemisphere has the bottom faces whose normals are not parallel to the XY plane. So the extrusion vector will have a Z component that will create the effect you see in the image below (which is an outer extrusion, while yours is an inner one, but it follows the same principle):

[image]

In blue are evidenced the vertex normals. Note how the last line of vertices has a non-horizontal normal projection.

To keep the bottom of the extrusion co-planar with hemisphere's bottom vertices you should start from a geometry who's last faces normals are **not** incident with XY plane:

[image]

The last picture was made by extruding the last line of vertices a bit on the Z-axis, so the geometry may not exactly represent a standard hemisphere.

To obtain a more precise result you can work with the **default UV sphere** settings and set an **odd number of rings**. This way, when you cut the sphere in half the faces will already have the correct normals and the resulting mesh will be a more precise approximation than extruding manually.

Comment: Carlo -- thank you! Your last solution, with the impar number of rings was an enormous help. Thank you!